# How to wake up my app (using service) WHEN another app launches?

Tags: java, android, service

It's a project for university that bewildered my team. We're creating an alternative voice control for android for disabled, that will launch when some specific apps launch.
When app destroyed, service wakes up. How to make it wait for another app launch? Another app is not our's, no broadcasting ability. We had an idea to make this service wake up every 5 minutes and check, but this may cause a memory leak. So this checking process must be non stop. In other words - another app's launch (we know it's package name) is a trigger.
We know that Stackoverflow isn't a freelance community or something like that, we just need a direction.

Comment: Declare an [AccessibilityService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService)

Comment: @Pawel an extra question - It should be turned on in the accessibility setting, am I right?